# Retain cursor position in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, css, contenteditable

I am trying to create a richtext area using contenteditable. The parser for the highlighting returns a html string which I replace the content of the element with (perhaps ineffective, thats the way it has to be for now).

The problem with contenteditable is that the cursor position is not retained after something like this, which I can understand.

Is there a way to retain this position? I could make the parser return a element representing where the caret should be (given the cursors offset in the text) if this would aid in a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could make the parser return a element representing where the caret should be

That would be enough. Suppose you parse the generated HTML and now you have a reference to the caret-should-be-here element in `sentinel`.

Use `document.createRange()` to create a DOM range. Let `here` be the new range. Call [`here.selectNode(sentinel)`](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-selectnode) to have the range surround the element.

Call [`here.deleteContents()`](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-deletecontents) to remove the dummy element.

Call `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()` to clear the current selection, which has gotten messed up by the HTML change.

Call `window.getSelection().addRange(here)` to put the cursor where the element used to be.

---

> is `sentinel` my anchor element?

Yeah, I guess.

---

> How do I fetch the cursor position in the string? ... I want the offset from the start of the string.

Let's start with the cursor position. The zeroth range of the window's selection should be the cursor's position. That is, the range's start and end are in the same place, at the cursor. However, these locations are expressed in a way that's geared toward DOM trees, rather than for string and offsets. They have a (start|end)Container and a (start|end)Offset. Check the DOM spec for what these mean.

You're interested in some sort of string offset. As I interpret it, this would be like, if you took a plaintext-only version of the subtree, what index corresponds to the range? There are multiple ways to define a plaintext version of a subtree. One is what the `textContent` property returns, where `foo<br>bar` gives "foobar". Some browsers define `innerText`, where `foo<br>bar` gives "foor\nbar". You've probably picked the one that you'll be using, but it's not stated in the question.

Anyway, here's an idea, but it might not be the right kind of offset for your app.

Set the window selection to a single range going from the beginning (wherever index 0 should be) to the cursor position.

Read [`window.getSelection().toString().length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.toString). In the browsers I've developed for, `toString` on a selection object gives results comparable to `innerText`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you care to elaborate? I have never worked with the API you've mentioned.

Comment: Also, the next problem would be to fetch the caret position in the string (ignoring tags)...

Comment: Sure, just identify what needs elaboration.

Comment: How do I fetch the cursor position in the string? There will be nested html tags and I want the offset from the start of the string. Also, is `sentinel` my anchor element?